# Find caller function by DLL loading in x64dbg

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

First of all I'm noob at debugging task and I'm try to self-study to learn how to debug exe using x64dbg.

I have EXE file packed by `themida`. i bypassed themida packing using `themida plugin` in x64dbg.after start EXE it has login function. i trying to bypass that login using x64dbg.when i clicked login button it's created a socket connection with server.

to create that connection it's loading `dnsapi.dll` after clicking login button (that dll not loading in startup), i can break process on loading dnsapi.dll using `dll breakpoints`.

my problem is how can i find what function load that dll for create that socket connection.

PS: i know that thing is actually illigle and not ethicle but i have motivation to lean that thing.so can anyone help me to figure it out how to find that login function called after click login button it whold be very helpfull.

** sorry for my bad english

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint at `LoadLibrary`? You can see the stack trace to see the return address, see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vq_VkoCgk3c